# Solving Volterra integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

I would like to solve $4u(t)+\int_0^t\sin(t-s)u(s)ds=5t, \ t\geqslant 0$.

Any ideas on how to approach this equation?

Comment: Maybe differentiate with respect to $t$ and try to solve for $u(t)$? You might have to use leibniz rule for the integral.

Comment: How many times is $u$ differentiable? If twice, then go with answers below

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Assume $u(\cdot)$ is continuous over $[0,\infty)$. Then one may differentiate the initial equation **twice**, using the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) getting

> $$
> u''(t)+u(t)=\frac{5}4t, \quad t\geqslant 0,
> $$

which can be classically solved using $u(0)=0$ and $u'(0)=\dfrac54$.

Comment: The first derivative is, I think: $\;4u'+\int_0^t\cos(t-s)u(s)ds=5\;$ , and the second one is:$$4u''-\overbrace{\int_0^t\sin(t-s)u(s)ds}^{-4u+5t}=0\implies 4u''+4u=-5t$$Besides the sign, how did you get $\;5u\;$ there, please?

Comment: @Joanpemo Typo corrected. Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure...and I also have a typo: it is, I think, $\;5t\;$ on the right side, not $\;-5t\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

Through Laplace transform the integral equation becomes
$$
4U(s)+\frac{1}{s^2+1}U(s)=\frac{5}{s^2}
$$
that is
$$
U(s)=\frac{5}{s^2}\frac{s^2+1}{4s^2+5}=\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{1}{4s^2+5}
$$
and then $$
u(t)=t+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\;t\right)\qquad t\ge 0
$$